# How to copy items from one list of ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to ArrayList<String>

Tags: arraylist

Ok, look. I have `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`   which contains 3 different `ArrayList<String>` items. I'm passing this `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to client.

I'm stuck at "extracting" items from this `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. How can I "extract" items from `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to 3 different `ArrayList<String>`??? In one turn(optionally); Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know there are three, and your `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` is called `bigList`, it's as simple as

```
ArrayList<String> first = bigList.get(0);
ArrayList<String> second = bigList.get(1);
ArrayList<String> third = bigList.get(2);
```

This will fail if there aren't three in there, of course.

If, instead, you want to loop over all of the `ArrayList<String>`s that are in there and do something with them, it's

```
for (ArrayList<String> innerList : bigList) {
    // do something with innerList
}
```

This will now work regardless of how many there are in there. (Even if there are none in there, it'll still work, in the sense of not generating an error: the `for` loop won't execute at all.)